# Keycloak global in vue

Tags: vue.js, router

Per to my understanding. The below config function should allow global access to my keycloak instance.

```
Main.js
myApp.config.globalProperties.$keycloak = keycloak;
```

and it's working everywhere as expected, but not in the router.js file.

```
router.js
console.log($keycloak.authenticated);
```

Returning undefined. Any tip on what should I do please?

The router.js looks like this:

```
const preventRoutes = {
  beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
    console.log(store.getters.getLoginState);
    // console.log(this.$keycloak.authenticated);
    if (store.getters.getLoginState === "true") {

      next();
    } else {

      
      next("/");
    }

  }

}


const routes = [
{
    path: '/dashboard',
    name: 'Dashboard',
    component: dashboard,
    ...preventRoutes,

  },

]


const router = createRouter({
  mode: "history",
  history: createWebHistory(process.env.BASE_URL),
  routes
})

export default router
```

Comment: Show the context of that console.log. Where are you calling it?

Comment: I'm calling it from the router.js file. Where I have all my routes.

Comment: Try changing it to "this.$keycloak".

Comment: Nope. Still (Cannot read property '$keycloak' of undefined)

Comment: Show more of the code of router.js

Comment: I edited the question to include how I am using it.

Comment: I am trying to do the same type off thing. I use app.config.globalProperties.keycloak = _keycloak to  save a copy of keystore in the global context.  I tried using app=getCurrenInstance() and const keycloak=app.appContext.config.globalProperties.keycloak  to acess it, but fails because  getCurrentInstance() only works in a setUp() endpoint,  I suspect you may running in to the same issue.

Comment: Well. I remember I couldn't access it at the end. I had to validate the login from the state variable.